# Create a procedure which will Update table records for all IDs coming into an input variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I was able to run the below query.

```
update tab_A set Analyzed=1 where id in (1,2,3,4)
```

Now I want to implement it through a stored procedure, something like given below.

```
  create procedure mark
  @variable varchar(max)
  as
  begin
    update tab_A set Analyzed=1 where id in (@variable)
  end
```

Comment: I really dont get what you're asking here...

Answer (score 1):

```
 Declare @string Nvarchar(Max)
 Set @string='update tab_A set Analyzed=1 where id IN ('''+Convert(Nvarchar(100),@variable)+''') '

 Print @string
 Exec (@string)
```

Comment: Try Below Query in your Procedure

Answer (score 1):

if there is no easier way i must create function 
if someone find this topic and need the same help i leave it here

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split] (
  @p_str NTEXT,
  @p_del CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @ret TABLE (item nvarchar(4000))
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @l_n INT;
  DECLARE @l_pos INT;
  DECLARE @l_tmp NVARCHAR(2000);

  SET @l_pos = 1;
  SET @l_tmp = SUBSTRING(@p_str, @l_pos, 2000);
  SET @l_n = CHARINDEX(@p_del, @l_tmp);

  WHILE(ISNULL(@l_n, 0) != 0) BEGIN
      INSERT INTO @ret
        SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@l_tmp, 1, @l_n - 1)));
    SET @l_pos = @l_pos + @l_n;
    SET @l_tmp = SUBSTRING(@p_str, @l_pos, 2000);
    SET @l_n = CHARINDEX(@p_del, @l_tmp);
  END;

   IF(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@p_str, @l_pos, (DATALENGTH(@p_str) / 2) - @l_pos + 1))) != '')
     INSERT INTO @ret
       SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@p_str, @l_pos, (DATALENGTH(@p_str) / 2) - @l_pos + 1)));

  RETURN;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE mark
    @variable VARCHAR(max)
  AS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(Max)
    SET @sql='update tab_A set Analyzed=1 where id IN ('''+Convert(NVARCHAR(max),@variable)+''') '
    EXEC (@sql)
  END
```